# C++ String to Int using StringStream not exact

Tags: c++, string, int, stringstream

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
stringstream convert1(Model_str.substr(2, 12));
cout << (Model_str.substr(2, 12)) << endl; //output = 0.999999
convert1>>vertex1[VertexCounter];
cout << vertex1[VertexCounter] << endl; //output = 0
```

Is there a reason why it is not being precise to 6 decimal places when placing it into my array?

Comment: Truncation, truncation, truncation.

Comment: Exactly what `int` were you *expecting* to get?

Comment: I was wanting the two outputs to be the same. So vertex[VertexCounter] should be 0.999999

Comment: truncation is standard behavior, not rounding.

Comment: What is the declaration of `vertex1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extract an `int` from a stream with `>>`, it reads for as long as there are characters that could be considered part of an `int`. Integers do not allow for fractional parts, so there are no decimal points in `int` values. It read the `0` from the stream, stored it in your `vertex1` array element (assuming `vertex1` is an array of `int`), and left the remaining characters on the input buffer for a later read operation to consume.

If you want to read a floating-point string from a stream, you at the *very least* need to read into a type that supports floating-point values, such as `float` or `double`. Whether you get the precise value you expected is another matter. The target type you choose might not be able to represent the exact value you want it to.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Using a double instead of int fixed it. Thank you for clearing that up for me :)